# Different markers for same data set in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a dataset consisting of two columns in a file. Is it possible to have different markers for each data point when plotting them?

I know I could do this by doing a BASH for loop generating a string of plot commands, but I was wondering if there is any way of doing it directly in gnuplot?

I was thinking something like marker type 1 for first data point, marker type 2 for the second data point, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the linecolor or the point size based on a column's value (or the row number), gnuplot knows the `linecolor variable` and `pointsize variable` parameters. However, that doesn't work for pointtype.

Gnuplot itself has some kinds of iteration loops. You would need to count your rows with `stats` and then iterate over each row using the loop variable and `every`:

```
stats 'myfile' nooutput
N = int(STATS_records-1)

plot for [i=0:N] 'myfile' every ::i::i pointtype (i+1)
```

Comment: That almost works. Off by one error on the last line though, should be `::i-1::i-1` if I'm not mistaken?